# Mocking another parameter on function not working when one of them is a callback interface

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I successfully did some tests of asynchronous function with only one callback interface as parameter with [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) library but when I try to do a test of same function with another parameter like a String or Integer I receive error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
>
> Invalid use of argument matchers!
>
> 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
>
> -> at com.example.presentation.presenter.MyCollectionPresenterTest.getComicListByHeroOK(MyCollectionPresenterTest.kt:97)
>
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>
> //incorrect:
>
> someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
>
> When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
>
> For example:
>
> //correct:
>
> someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
>
> For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

I´m sure I´m mocking properly callback interface with any() but I don´t know if I´m mocking integer parameter correctly. I tried with `any()`, `anyInt()`, `eq(1)` and `any() as Int` but always the same error.

Here is the class that I want to test:

```
@PerFragment
class MyCollectionPresenter @Inject constructor(private val useCase: GetComicListByHeroUseCase) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var view: MyCollectionView
    lateinit var models: List<ComicModel>

    fun getComicListByHero(heroId: Int) {
        useCase.execute(heroId, object : HeroUseCase.GetComicListByHeroCallback {
            override fun onComicListReceived(comicList: List<Comic>) {
                models = ComicModelMapper.toModel(comicList)
                view.setItems(models)
            }

            override fun onError() {
                view.showMessage()
            }

        })
    }
}
```

And this is the test class:

```
class MyCollectionPresenterTest : UnitTest() {

    private lateinit var presenter: MyCollectionPresenter
    @Mock
    private lateinit var useCase: GetComicListByHeroUseCase
    @Mock
    private lateinit var view: MyCollectionView

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        presenter = MyCollectionPresenter(useCase)
        initializeView()
    }

    @Test
    fun getComicListByHeroOK() {
        setupGetComicsCallbackOK()

        presenter.getComicListByHero(any())

        verify(presenter.view).setItems(emptyList())
    }

    @Test
    fun getComicListByHeroError() {
        setupGetComicsCallbackError()

        presenter.getComicListByHero(any())

        verify(presenter.view).showMessage()
    }

    private fun initializeView() {
        presenter.view = view
    }

    private fun setupGetComicsCallbackError() {
        doAnswer {
            val callback = it.arguments[0] as HeroUseCase.GetComicListByHeroCallback
            callback.onError()
            null
        }.`when`(useCase).execute(any(), any())
    }

    private fun setupGetComicsCallbackOK() {
        doAnswer {
            val callback = it.arguments[0] as HeroUseCase.GetComicListByHeroCallback
            callback.onComicListReceived(emptyList())
            null
        }.`when`(useCase).execute(any(), any())
    }
}
```

This is base unit test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
abstract class UnitTest {

    @Suppress("LeakingThis")
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val injectMocks = InjectMocksRule.create(this@UnitTest)
}
```

And this is a class for inject mocks rule:

```
class InjectMocksRule {

    companion object {
        fun create(testClass: Any) = TestRule { statement, _ ->
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(testClass)
            statement
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help and excuse my english.

Regards!

**UPDATE: I found the solution and posted as answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I know what I was doing wrong. First at all, `it.argument[1]` because callback is the second parameter of the function that I want to mock the answer.

And the other thing is that I was mocking the parameter of the function that I want to test `presenter.getComicListByHero(1)`.

Here is the revised code:

```
@Test
fun getComicListByHeroError() {
    setupGetComicsCallbackError()

    presenter.getComicListByHero(1)

    verify(presenter.view).showMessage()
}

private fun setupGetComicsCallbackError() {
    doAnswer {
        val callback = it.arguments[1] as HeroUseCase.GetComicListByHeroCallback
        callback.onError()
        null
    }.`when`(useCase).execute(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt(), any())
}
```

Thank you very much to @voghDev for his help